# Fine tuning QGIS project for Qfield

Tags: qgis, qfield, configuration

I am a beginner with Qfield but long time QGIS user and geodata professional.
I am very pleased with Qfield so far (free account only yet).
However, I seem unable to hide fields in the export to Qfield.
This is possible within the QGIS project and it could be valuable to export that setting and bring only some fields into the mobile app, to reduce screen scrolling.

Comment: Under Attributes form tab of Layer properties dialog, use Drag and Drop Designer instead of Autogenerate. Then you can select which fields are included in the attributes form.